# IntelliJ Android - Delete application before debug

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Does anyone know if there is a way to get create a Debug Configuration in IntelliJ that will remove the application before launch? This can be done via adb commands so it should be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Run/Debug configuration there are some options under **Before Launch** section, you can [create](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/ant-build-tool-window.html) an **Ant** `build.xml` file with a simple [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) target that will run `adb` with appropriate options to uninstall your application from the device (or you can use special [AndroidAnt](http://code.google.com/p/autoandroid/wiki/AndroidAnt) tasks that can be installed separately).

Comment: could you put your build.xml please?

Comment: @crazycoder How can I uninstall the app before `Make` runs in Android Studio?